# Android camera setPictureSize distort camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera

For some reasons when I use camera setPictureSize the camera preview is become distort. Have anybody face that problem?

Comment: i have also seen this happen - it seems like there is some kind of interaction between the picturesize and the previewsize that is not mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

According to my experience there is a dependency between setPictureSize and camera preview size.

Most of tutorials like official (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) calculates preview size depending on actual screen size. But this won't work with actual picture size. So I now calculate optimal preview size according to selected picture size.

I would recommend to look at Android camera source code of Android 2.3 that is not so complicated: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git/+/android-cts-2.3_r12